# Azure Maps - pins disappear

Tags: azure-maps

I have an application that leverages Azure Maps to show pins of various locations on a map.  All works great, but when I zoom out, some of the pins will disappear.  When I zoom back in they reappear.

Is there a way to keep the map from hiding the pins even when zoomed out?  I have set my iconOptions in the layer to...

```
layer = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
    iconOptions: {
        ignorePlacement: true
    },
});
```

But that hasn't really helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also set the `allowOverlap` option to `true`. If displaying text in a symbol layer, and you want that to always show, set the same options under the `textOptions` of the symbol layer.

```
layer = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
    iconOptions: {
        allowOverlap: true,
        ignorePlacement: true
    }
});
```

Comment: setting the above properties in iconOptions and textOptions, I was able to keep the pins from disappearing.